# "Use the approach that you like more"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

- You can do it multiple ways. [Skipped]. Use the approach that you like more.
- You can do it multiple ways. [Skipped]. Use the approach you like more.
- You can do it multiple ways. [Skipped]. Use whichever approach you like more.

Are all of these sentences grammatical and idiomatic? What is the difference in their meaning? And which one is the most precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first sentence, I suggest
"There are several ways you can do it."
The distinction here is that you won't do it multiple ways, but in one of several ways.

For the second sentence, all three of the options are idiomatic and mean the same. You could use the word "best" in place of "more".